# Automatically create a copy of a static variable for each derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance, static-variables

I have a base class with a static variable. I want to create derived subclasses which will automatically have their own unshared static variable. Ideally it would look like this:

```
class Parent
{
     Texture2D picture;
     static Texture2D pictureOrigin;

     Parent()
     {
         picture = pictureOrigin;
         /*Loading the static origin to an instance variable
         because I might want to have more pictureOrigins 
         and alternate them or perhaps change the picture
         of the instance based on a certain event, etc.*/            
     }
}

class Subclass1 : Parent
{
    Subclass1() : base()
    { }
}

class Subclass2 : Parent
{
    Subclass2() : base()
    { }
}

void main()
{
    Parent.pictureOrigin = Load("pictureForParent"); 
    Subclass1.pictureOrigin = Load("pictureForSubclass1");
    Subclass2.pictureOrigin = Load("pictureForSubclass2");
    //Then creating instances of the classes and drawing them, etc.
}
```

But what happens is that they all get the last loaded image (pictureForSubclass2) because the static variable `pictureOrigin` is shared between them.

The quickest fix is manually adding new static variable `pictureOrigin` to each subclass and hiding the `pictureOrigin` variable of the base class:

```
class Subclass1 : Parent
{
    new static Texture2D pictureOrigin;

    Subclass1() : base()
    {
         picture = pictureOrigin;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, creating abstract methods or similar to ensure the creation of the new static variable in the subclasses. But it seems like too much of a hassle and not too elegant.  Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Static seems like a bad idea, any reason why it must be static? You could rather load the image resources to some image store, and then supply the required images to each instance?

Comment: In your code, Subclass1 and Subclass2 are not inheriting from Parent.

Comment: You could make `Parent` generic, like `class Parent<T> where T : Parent<T>` and then for inheritance specify the type of the subclass: `class Subclass1 : Parent<Subclass1>`. You would then exploit the fact that each unique combination of `<T>` types will get their own copy of all static fields. Having said that, I would try to get rid of the `static` keyword altogether and find a different way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question smells like a poor design. Static variables are generally poor practice in my opinion, and proper object-oriented design can eliminate the need to ever use static members.

Try refactoring like so:

```
public class Parent
{
    private Texture2D texture;

    public Parent(Texture2D texture) {
        this.texture = texture;
    }

    public Texture2D Picture { get {
            return texture;
        }
    }
}

public class SubClass1 : Parent
{
    public SubClass1(Texture2D texture) : base(texture) {

    }
}
```

Let me elaborate on why static is a poor choice:

1. Your class is now only good for a single bitmap. Eliminates the possibility to reuse a class for several bitmaps (this is the limitation you're fighting against)
2. Your class is not in a valid state until the static setter is called. Generally objects, once constructed, should be in a valid state. It won't be obvious to others if they're using your object that they have to statically set the bitmap on the class.
3. Breaks the natural garbage collection. For example if you wanted the Texture2D object to be garbage collected when all the instances of SubClass are collected it wouldn't work with your static design. Alternatively, if you use a oop design (like suggested) you have the flexibility to garbage collect or not depending on your use cases.
4. Makes threading more complicated. Statics are global, so you need global mutexes to guarantee thread-safety.
5. Makes testing more difficult. If you want to unit test the class, you have to make sure that the static is cleaned up after every test, and you couldn't run two unit tests against this class in parallel.
6. Makes memory management inflexible. If you use object-oriented design you can choose to share bitmaps among all instances, or allocate a new bitmap for every instance.

Comment: I've got a game. The parent defines some general object of the game (like coordinates, move method, etc.). The subclasses are the actual objects with defined properties but their picture has to be loaded from the Game class. I used to give them the picture with construction `someObject(int x, int y, Texture2D pic)` but it seemed better to save the picture to the class so I don't have to send it to the constructor every time I made an instance of the class.

Comment: The constructor sounds like a better way to do it actually. Don't worry about passing the reference around because it is a reference only.. it won't copy your image every time you pass it to a constructor so you'll get the benefit of sharing memory among all instances if you construct them with a reference to the same Texture2D.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a static `Dictionary<Type,Texture2D>`.

```
public class Parent
{
    // Keep a table of types and default values
    protected static Dictionary<Type, Texture2D> pictureOrigin;

    static Parent()
    {
        // static ctor. initialize table
        pictureOrigin=new Dictionary<Type, Texture2D>();
    }

    internal static void SetDefaultPicture<T>(Texture2D picture)
    {
        // Set default based on type T
        Type type=typeof(T);
        pictureOrigin[type]=picture;
    }

    public Parent()
    {
        // Assign default based on this type
        Picture=pictureOrigin[this.GetType()];
    }
    public Texture2D Picture { get; set; }
}

public class SubClass1 : Parent
{
}
public class SubClass2 : Parent
{
}
```

to be used as

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Texture2D picture0 = Load("pictureForParent");
        Texture2D picture1=Load("pictureFroSubClass1");
        Texture2D picture2=Load("pictureFroSubClass2");

        Parent.SetDefaultPicture<Parent>(picture0);
        Parent.SetDefaultPicture<SubClass1>(picture1);
        Parent.SetDefaultPicture<SubClass2>(picture2);            
    }
```

Here is the debug of an example. It shows that `SubClass1` initialized with `pictureForSubClass1` automatically.

[image: res]

Answer (score 0):

A static member that declared in generic type is basically declared per class and its generic.
For example `Foo<Bar>.baz` is not equal to `Foo<Qux>.baz`.

So basically you can do this:

```
abstract class Parent<T>
{
     Texture2D picture;
     static Texture2D pictureOrigin;

     Parent()
     {
         picture = pictureOrigin;
         /*Loading the static origin to an instance variable
         because I might want to have more pictureOrigins 
         and alternate them or perhaps change the picture
         of the instance based on a certain event, etc.*/            
     }
}

class Parent : Parent<Parent>
{
    Parent () : base()
    { }
}

class Subclass1 : Parent<Subclass1>
{
    Subclass1() : base()
    { }
}

class Subclass2 : Parent<Subclass2>
{
    Subclass2() : base()
    { }
}

void main()
{
    Parent.pictureOrigin = Load("pictureForParent"); 
    Parent<Subclass1>.pictureOrigin = Load("pictureForSubclass1");
    Parent<Subclass2>.pictureOrigin = Load("pictureForSubclass2");
}
```